# MySQL Query Order by the query itself

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have this query:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `products` WHERE `id` = 0 OR `id` = 4 OR `id` = 2
```

- basically, I want the query to be sorted by the order of the OR statements (basically, the first returned object would be with ID 0, the second would be 4, and third be 2).
  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select name from products WHERE id=0 OR id= 4 OR id=2 order by FIELD(id,0,4,2);
```

FIELD()  Returns the index (position) of 0 in the 4, 2,... list. Returns 0 if 0 is not found.

**Note :** this will Slow down your query a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you need to use field() function in order by as

```
SELECT `name` FROM `products` WHERE `id` = 0 OR `id` = 4 OR `id` = 2
order by field(id,0,4,2)
```

Here is a [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da7fc/1)
The table is not the same in your case but you may get an idea how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `FIND_IN_SET()` function:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE id IN (0,4,3) ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '0,4,3');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another idea -

SELECT `name` FROM `products` 
WHERE `id` = 0 OR `id` = 4 OR `id` = 2
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id=0 THEN 1 WHEN 'id'=4 THEN 2 WHEN 'id'=2 THEN 3 ELSE 'id' END